# How to delete a file from a directory using ftp disk in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I'm trying to delete a file from another server that is connected to my project by ftp.
This is my code :

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->delete('avatars/'.$user->avatar);
```

But this error occurs :

```
ftp_delete(): avatars/user2.jpg: Is a directory
```

And its my ftp configs in filesystems.php :

```
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
    'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
    'root' => '/public_html/storage',
    'ssl' => false,
],
```

What is the problem?

Comment: show filesystem created for ftp in filesystem.php

Comment: also whats the path of ftp is pointing

Comment: try removing   'root' => '/public_html/storage', this path

Comment: @JohnLobo But i want to put and delete my files inside this path

Comment: point your ftp to /public_html/storage.

Comment: @JohnLobo Thanks! I did what u say and after that I rolled back changes and it surprisingly worked! I don't know what was the problem.

Comment: @JohnLobo Oh maybe it's because a / before the root (I changed /public_html/storage to public_html/storage)

Comment: yes i think so.glad that you have solved your issue